# Handle widget click action when iOS app in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, widget

When the widget is clicked I can handle using the following method if the app is not running-

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

But if the app is in the background how to handle the action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handleOpenURL` will be called no matter if App is in the background mode or not.

> Official document:
>   If a URL arrives while your app is suspended or
>   running in the background, the system moves your app to the foreground
>   prior to calling this method.

And what influences the calling:

> This method is not called if the delegate returns NO from both the
>   `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and
>   `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` methods. (If only one of
>   the two methods is implemented, its return value determines whether
>   this method is called.) If your app implements the
>   `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method instead of
>   `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, this method is called to
>   open the specified URL after the app has been initialized.

And it's better to use following method since iOS9.0:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```